# BeanFacotry and Bean of same type

Tags: java, spring

I have two services that implements my service interface, and I want to select the right service based on some rule at runtime, for example:

```
public interface Service { public String doSomething(String param); }

@Component("serviceAimpl") 
public class ServiceAImpl implements Service{ 
    public String doSomething(String param){ 
        return param + "A";
    }
}

@Component("serviceBimpl") 
public class ServiceBImpl implements Service{ 
    public String doSomething(String param){
        return param;
    }
}
```

The ServiceAImpl must be used when param starts with "1" and the ServiceBImpl must be used otherwise, is there any way to do something like the above:

```
@Component public class ServiceImpl implements Service {
    @Autowired private Map<String, Service> services;
    public String doSomething(String param) {
         if(param.startsWith("1")
             return services.get("serviceAimpl").doSomething(param);
         else
             return services.get("serviceBimpl").doSomething(param);
    }
}
```

This way the factory is of the same type as the beans itself and so there is no need to create a new type to get the bean and then use the bean. Is that valid in spring or not? Is there any approach or convention to do something like the described above (ignore the fact that Im only concatenating Strings there) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just use two separate `@Autowired` properties like so:

```
@Service("serviceAimpl") 
public class ServiceAImpl implements Service{ 
    public String doSomething(String param){ 
        return param + "A";
    }
}

@Service("serviceBimpl") 
public class ServiceBImpl implements Service{ 
    public String doSomething(String param){
        return param;
    }
}
@Service("mainService")
public class ServiceImpl {
    @Autowired
    private ServiceAImpl serviceAimpl;
    @Autowired
    private ServiceBImpl serviceBimpl;

    public String doSomething(String param) {
         if(param.startsWith("1")
             return this.serviceAimpl.doSomething(param);
         else
             return this.serviceBimpl.doSomething(param);
    }
}
```

EDIT: If you want to autowire a Map, list, set of some properties here is an interesting [article](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-injecting-lists-maps).

Comment: Thank you, the article helped a lot to do what I was searching for that is using the composite pattern (didnt know the name as of the time of writing the question) in a spring way.

Answer (score 1):

Nikol has given a good solution which i would do as well. But dont know your requirement fully, so you might be intrested in below option as well.

[From spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-autowired-annotation)

> Even typed Maps can be autowired as long as the expected key type is String. The Map values will contain all beans of the expected type, and the keys will contain the corresponding bean names:

Thus it is possible to get bean name and bean and use it the way you want to use it

```
@Autowired
private Map<String, Service > services;

if(somecondition)
   services.get("serviceAimpl"). doSomething();
else 
   services.get("ServiceBImpl"). doSomething()
```